# insertion sort using dynamic memory

Tags: c, dynamic

I do not know how to pass parameters to `insertSort`. I am also not certain if I am using `scanf` correctly.

I want the dynamic array like this: [image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void insertSort(int LENGTH, int *arr)
{
    int temp;

    for(int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)
    {
        temp = arr[i];  

        for(int j=i+1; j<LENGTH; j++)
        {
            if( temp > arr[j] )
            {
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int LENGTH = 10;
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*LENGTH);                  //create dynamic  memory
    memset(arr, 0, LENGTH);                                 //initialize the space

    printf("please enter nums length : %d\n", LENGTH);

    for(int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)                             //put numbers to the dynamic space
    {
        printf("%d index : ", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)                             //print those space
    printf("%3d", arr[i]);

    insertSort(&LENGTH, &arr);                              //SORT !

    for(int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)
    printf("%3d", arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Your `scanf` use looks basically ok.  The arguments to `insertSort()` do not.  That function expects an `int` and an `int *`.  You are instead providing an `int *` and an `int **`.  Get rid of the `&` operators in the argument list.

Comment: `memset(arr, 0, LENGTH);` only sets the first `10-bytes` of `arr` to zero. You allocate with `sizeof(int)*LENGTH`, why don't you do the same with `memset`? (and NO you do not use `scanf` correctly, you fail to **validate the return** and handle (1) EOF, (2) matching or input failure, and (3) good input and (4) empty the input buffer in case of (2) above)

Comment: I edited them like insertionSort(LENGTH, arr) and void insertionSort(int * LENGTH, int **arr)

but the error poped up...

                ^
dynamic_sort.c:11:8: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   temp = arr[i]; ////////////////and dynamic_sort.c:41:21: warning: passing argument 2 of 'insertSort' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  insertSort(LENGTH, arr);        //SORT !
                     ^~~

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this one piece at a time. For starters, your `insertSort` is not an insertion sort. An insertion sort implementation looks like:

```
void insertSort(int LENGTH, int *arr)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < LENGTH; i++) 
    {
        int tmp = arr[i], j;

        for (j = i; j >= 1 && tmp < arr[j-1]; j--)
            arr[j] = arr[j-1];

        arr[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Next, when you are testing functions, etc.., forego the user input and just test your function with a fixed set of data as a test-case, e.g.

```
int main(void) {

    int arr[] = { 10, 2, 8, 5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 9, 1 },
        nmemb = (int)(sizeof arr/sizeof *arr);

    insertSort (nmemb, arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < nmemb; i++)
        printf ("%3d", arr[i]);

    putchar ('\n');
}
```

Lastly, `scanf`. You cannot begin to use `scanf` correctly unless you **validate its return**. Further, in your case, what happens if the user types `"ten"` instead of the number `10` -- try it...

Any time you are taking user-input, **you** must account for each character that remains in the input buffer (`stdin` here). This is especially true when taking input with `scanf` (or family) due to the way `scanf` handles *input* or *matching* failures. When either occurs, *no further characters are read*, and any offending characters are left unread in the input buffer -- just waiting to bite you again on your next attempted read (generally resulting in an infinite loop if you are taking input within a loop)

(this is one of the primary reason a *line-oriented* function such as `fgets` or POSIX `getline` are recommended for taking user input)

`scanf` can be used, if used correctly. This means **you** are responsible for checking the **return** of `scanf` *every time*. You must handle *three conditions*

1. `(return == EOF)` the user canceling input by generating a manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or on windows <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd>, but see [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/));
2. `(return == expected No. of conversions)` indicating a successful read -- it is then up to you to check whether the input meets any additional criteria (e.g. positive integer, positive floating-point, etc..); and
3. otherwise, you must handle the *matching* or *input* failure and you must account for every character that may be left in your input buffer. (generally you will scan forward in the input buffer until a `'\n'` or `EOF` is found discarding any extraneous characters that remain)

If you do your job, you can successfully use `scanf` as needed.

Comment: Thanks ! really helpful i will try  to edit them

but quick question ! **for (j = i; j >= 1 && tmp < arr[j-1]; j--)** how does it work ... ??   i have seen before like this shape

Comment: Most shops I've worked in like spaces around the operators, such as +, -, /, %, etc, rather than cramming everything together which makes it hard to read, plus doing so is more consistent with the rest of your style.

Comment: If you look, the `j` loop starts at `i` and then works toward the beginning until it finds the element where `tmp < arr[j-1]` is not true (meaning it finds the element where `tmp` is bigger than the element of `arr`) before it and it inserts `tmp` (`arr[i]`) there). By requiring `j >= 1` it makes sure that the index tested with `arr[j-1]` is never less than `0`)

Comment: @clearlight, it can be separated of course, but that is a convenient way of writing the simple for loop `for (j = i; ...; j--)`, you just have two conditions to test `j >= 1 && tmp < arr[j-1]`. You could use `j >= 1` alone and then within the loop test `if (arr[j-1] < tmp) break;`. Whatever is clearer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  Strictly a syntax thing. Any company I've been in that enforced any kind of code styling convention required a space character on each side of an operator.  Just used to seeing it that way. Before I went through the grinder in system/OS groups I used to squish things together and thought it was compact/efficient. Now it looks dense, thoughtless and harder to read.

Comment: @clearlight, yes no worries. I can tell you that the companies I've worked at since '89 (including at JSC, Rockwell Space Operations, etc.) really don't have one industry standard they follow. What is the famous phrase "The Code is more a collection of guidelines anyway....". I prefer a "no cuddle up" with conditionals and functions, etc. with the space between the `if (` or `funcname (` rather than within the parens. Clean and readable is the key. I have had [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf) for more than 20 years (I left in '95)